# Azure B2C - Send Groups In Claims to SAML SP Using REST API That Queries Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to return group claim in a SignupSign custom policy in Azure B2C to the SAML test app found here https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/. Here's of what I have done so far: -

1. Created a HTTP trigger PowerShell Azure Function that returns a comma-separated list of groups a user belongs to after querying the MS Graph API. I call it outside B2C and it works fine.
2. In the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file, added a claim type element like so

   ```
     <BuildingBlocks>
   <ClaimsSchema>
     <ClaimType Id="groups">
       <DisplayName>Comma delimited list of group names</DisplayName>
       <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
       <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
         <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="groups" />
         <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="groups" />
         <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" />
       </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
       <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
     </ClaimType>
   </ClaimsSchema>
   ```
3. In the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml I also added a Technical profile  and an orchestration step like so

   ```
       <TechnicalProfile Id="GetUserGroups">
         <DisplayName>Retrieves security groups assigned to the user</DisplayName>
         <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
         <Metadata>
           <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://morphitgraphapicall.azurewebsites.net/api/GetGroupsFromGraph?objectID=objectId</Item>
           <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
           <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
           <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
         </Metadata>
         <InputClaims>
           <InputClaim Required="true" ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
         </InputClaims>
         <OutputClaims>
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />
         </OutputClaims>
         <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
       </TechnicalProfile>
   ```

   ...

   ```
       <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
         <ClaimsExchanges>
           <ClaimsExchange Id="GetUserGroups" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GetUserGroups" />
         </ClaimsExchanges>
       </OrchestrationStep>
   ```
4. In the relying party file, added an output claim like so

[relying party file output claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KBFZ.png)

But I can't seem to get the groups claim passed to the SP application. I can tell that the REST API is being called because being on the Azure Functions consumption plan, there is a cold start if I haven't called the function for a bit which leads to a pause after sign-in.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you fix the last snippet showing the output claim in the relying party section

Comment: Oh thanks! Didn't notice that.

Comment: Hey Jas Suri, ot sure why byt the formatting won't take so i added a screenshot.

Comment: Looks ok, would need to see the entire set of policy files to debug further. You should also enable App Insights so you can confirm what your API is responding with, and whether the Groups claims is actually populated in the B2C claims bag - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

Comment: is this example works fine ?